# unique attribute count json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

i have a json file as below

```
 {"Teams": [
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
]}
```

Whats the best way to extract the unique attribute values of **f3** .

Here in our example I should store the unique f3 attribute in an array that is array should have `["Jun-2016","May-2016","Aug-2016"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method

```js
var data= {"Teams": [
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
]};

var res = data.Teams.reduce(function(arr, ele) {
  // check element already exist if not push the value to the array
  if (arr.indexOf(ele.f3) === -1) arr.push(ele.f3);
  return arr;
  // set initial value as empty array
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: can you change the code to push the data to json array instead of array the result should be in the below format {"f3":"Aug-2016","f3":"May-2016","f3":"Jun-2016"}  ?

Comment: @user3349850 : Json array? `JSON.stringify(rs)`

Comment: @user3349850 : `{"f3":"Aug-2016","f3":"May-2016","f3":"Jun-2016"} == {"f3":"Jun-2016"}` , but this one is possible `[{"f3":"Aug-2016"},{"f3":"May-2016"},{"f3":"Jun-2016"}]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrnew = []


var data = {
  "Teams": [{
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "May-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "Aug-2016",
    "color": "R"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "Jun-2016",
    "color": "R"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "May-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "May-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "Jun-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "Jun-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "Aug-2016",
    "color": "R"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "May-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "Jun-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "f1": "Currency",
    "f2": "All",
    "f3": "May-2016",
    "color": "G"
  }, ]
}



$.each(data.Teams, function(i, v) {
  
  if ($.inArray(v.f3, arrnew) == -1) {
    arrnew.push(v.f3);
  };

})

console.log(arrnew)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Iterate the data
2. Create new array and check if value exist in array if not push the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` & `indexOf` methods to find the unique f3 values

```
var x= {"Teams": [
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
]}
var _m =(x.Teams);
var uniquef3 = [];
_m.forEach(function(item){
 if(uniquef3.indexOf(item.f3) ==-1){
    uniquef3.push(item.f3)
 }

})
console.log(uniquef3)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/C97DJ/240/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var x ={"Teams": [
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
]}

newaArr =[]

angular.forEach(x.Teams,function(val,index){
if(newaArr.indexOf(val.f3) ==-1){
newaArr.push(val.f3)
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done is some optimized way. you can cache the unique values for f3. and next time just check with their existence with the hasOwnProperty of javascript. This will reduce the complexity of search the existence.

```
 var Teams = [
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
];

var output=[];
var cache = {};

for(var i in Teams) {
  if(!cache.hasOwnProperty(Teams[i].f3)) {
    cache[Teams[i].f3] = null;
  }
}
for(var key in cache) {
  output.push(key);
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var unique={}
var kt= {"Teams": [
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Aug-2016","color":"R"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"Jun-2016","color":"G"},
{"id":"1","f1":"Currency","f2":"All","f3":"May-2016","color":"G"},
]};

kt.Teams.forEach(function(value){unique[value.f3]=0;});
console.log(Object.keys(unique));
```

Hope it will help